# How to change the fonts used in Foxit Reader?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I really want to use Foxit Reader as my default PDF reader for its Tab Interface, and low memory footprint. Having tried mutiple times over the years the only thing that is stopping me are the Fonts. PDF in Adobe Reader looks Regular, but PDF Rendered in Foxit Looks Ugly.

Would this solution works in Chrome as well? Since i record Chrome is using Foxit Reader as its embedded PDF engine.

And is there any reasons why Fonts are used differently in Adobe and Foxit Reader?

Comment: [You're not the only one to notice this](http://www.pretentiousname.com/adobe_pdf_x64_fix/pdf_comparison/). Since the reader just uses the fonts embedded in the PDF, unless Foxit improves its rendering engine it's unlikely you can fix it at your end.